# Why 29 A's in the new HP ilo bug?

Tags: authentication

In the newest authentication bypass exploit:

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/44005/

29 "A"'s needed.

Q: But why? isn't buffers/variables usually the power of 2? so 16, 32, 64, etc.

(just to know more when I am fuzzing an application, how many "A"'s should I use in general :) since I was using the power of 2 and the power of 2 + 1 so far, but this 29 A's wouldn't even fit the power of 2 - 1)

Comment: 29*"A"s are 29 bytes. Also what do you mean with "_isn't buffers/variables usually the power of 2? so 16, 32, 64, etc._" ? You can define an array that is made to store certain number of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the code wrote it so the max values for the field were 28 most likely, 29 breaks it. As @gameOver said you can define a variable to be any length you want.

Here is a really silly python example of a buffer overflow, it is just dumb but it shows how an arbitrary limit is defined then breaks when it is exceeded.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("ERROR: Must supply 1 argument.") 
    quit()
else:
    userInput=sys.argv[1]

fixedBuff=[None]*10
j=0
for i in userInput:
    print("Appending: " + str(i))
    fixedBuff[j]=i
    j=j+1
```

If you run that and increase your argument it breaks eventually. Very simplistic but it helps to show how a buffer overflow works.

Comment: Exactly! It's good to mention that most scripting languages like python, handle this kind of errors by throwing exceptions, but low-level languages like C will simply crash and most of the time in an exploitable way.

Comment: wow, thanks! :) any further great hints, how many "A"'s should I use when I am fuzzing? Or just use a very-very long one?

Comment: There is no fixed value, everyone writes their code differently. So increase by 1 in a loop and keep trying.